# Is an unordered list element allowed inside a description details element?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Can a `dd` element contain a `ul` element? Like this:

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Lorem</dt>
  <dd>Sed lectus</dd>
  <dt>Vestibulum</dt>
  <dd>
    <ul>
      <li>viverra nec</li>
      <li>blandit vel</li>
      <li>egestas et</li>
    </ul>
  </dd>
  <dt>Suspendisse</dt>
  <dd>Nulla quam</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is valid for a `<dd>` to contain a `<ul>`. According to the [HTML Spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-dd-element), `<dd>` elements should contain [flow content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#flow-content-2). Unordered lists are considered flow content.

However, if each of the items in your example are alternate descriptions for the proceeding `<dt>` term, they **should not** be marked up in an unordered list and should instead be marked up using a series of `<dd>` elements.

For instance, the following is valid HTML, but **semantically incorrect**—because it implies that the entire list is a singular description for the term.

```
<dl>
  <dt>Firefox</dt>
  <dd>
    <ul>
      <li>A free, open source, cross-platform, graphical web browser developed by the Mozilla Corporation and hundreds of volunteers.</li>
      <li>The Red Panda also known as the Lesser Panda, Wah, Bear Cat or Firefox, is a mostly herbivorous mammal, slightly larger than a domestic cat (60 cm long).</li>
    </ul>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

The valid **and semantically correct** way to mark up this content is:

```
<dl>
  <dt>Firefox</dt>
  <dd>A free, open source, cross-platform, graphical web browser developed by the Mozilla Corporation and hundreds of volunteers.</dd>
  <dd>The Red Panda also known as the Lesser Panda, Wah, Bear Cat or Firefox, is a mostly herbivorous mammal, slightly larger than a domestic cat (60 cm long).</dd>
</dl>
```